# How to delay the speed of uploading files for local development?

Tags: javascript

How can I slow the speed of uploading a file in my local development? The reason behind this is to show the user some options when the file is getting uploaded.

Currently, the uploading is too fast so that I find it difficult to test my changes.

Any help is appreciated. JavaScript is preferred. No jQuery.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with Javascript. It has to be on the server side.

Comment: You probably want to do that on the server side. What language are you using?

Comment: -1 you cant do that, it's like pulling leg while running. so u can try uploading larger file and test the speed. or get the slow bandwidth

Comment: @alexn My server side code is in Java. How do i do it with java?

Comment: Yes you can. See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface ; I used `trickle` (linux) a few times and am quite happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the java sleep function

```
  sleep(8000); // prevents further executions for 8 seconds
```